# Vuejs Component is not responding to "mouseleave" event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm setting up a navbar navigation with dynamic component; such that when you hover on the navbar-link an appropriate component shows up and when you leave the component disappears. The components do show up but on "mouseleave" it does not disappear or respond to the event. A sample code is displayed below.

I've tried other events such as `@click` and still no response.

```
<keep-alive>
  <component :is="selectedComponent" v-if="showComponent"  @mouseleave="showComponent = false"></component>
</keep-alive>
```

I expect the component to disappear on `mouseleave`

Answer (score 3):

When you put an event listener on a component it will only be listening for events emitted by that component using `$emit`. So if you aren't calling `this.$emit('mouseleave')` in your component that listener will never be called.

You could listen for the event internally and emit it but more likely what you're looking for is the `native` modifier, which will attach DOM events directly onto the outermost element of the component:

```html
@mouseleave.native="showComponent = false"
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Note that components differ from native HTML elements in this regard. What you did would have worked fine if you were using a `<div>` but it won't work for a component.